# IntelliJ IDEA azure ARM template intellisense

Tags: azure, intellij-idea, intellisense, azure-rm-template

I am new to azure ARM templates... I would like to use IntelliJ IDEA, it has azure support plugin from Microsoft. I have whole project (java+maven+azure) in IDEA. I would like to work with related ARM template in the same place. ARM template documentation is huge... So, any in-IDE highlight/intellisense would be appreciated.

Problems:

- when I open (regular file) JSON file (with schema) with ARM template

  - CTRL+SPACE shows possible values from schema, but it is really slow (like 8seconds) every time! Which makes it unusable. There isn't a cache of any type?
  - it does not offer all supported values, the latest "2019-04-01" is missing. But the schema contains it "$ref": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/Microsoft.Storage.json#/resourceDefinitions/storageAccounts"
  - CTRL+SPACE on location really shows list of possible locations. Unfortunately, it shows it "names" instead of IDs. "West Europe" vs. "westeurope". So it creates invalid template.
- when I open deployment from Azure Explorer, it shows ARM template and its parameters in split view side-by-side. It is very fancy.

  - BUT... it do nothing to CTRL+SPACE.
  - split view keep changing widths all the times )-:

Questions:

- How do you work with ARM templates?
- Is it so slow for you too?
- Is there somewhere a newer schema definition? (MS docs said that https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json# is latest)

I understand that half of it goes to IDEA team, half to azure plugin team... but it just seems to me, that I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

... for anybody interested in ARM template in IntelliJ IDEA ...

IDEA is not currently (2020) ready for effective work (unfortunately). Azure Toolkit for IDEA plugin needs more work... lets hope for future releases.

Free Visual Studio Code with Azure resource manager extensions is smooth and fully integrated.